# how to process vim plugin detect filetype different from vim detect

Tags: vim

I install [vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown),but this plugin detect markdown file as `mkd`(by `ftdetect/mkd.vim`), while vim detect it as `markdown`.
Also some my plugin and config depends `markdonw`.
So how to use it harmonious, without change vim-markdown, and vim `filetype.vim`？

Comment: They have a pending pull request to change `mkd` to `markdown`: https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/pull/161

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following to your `.vimrc`

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.md,*.markdown setlocal filetype=markdown " Automatically set filetype for Markdown files"
```

also, if you use markdown a lot, I could give a try to [pandoc markdown](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#pandocs-markdown) and use [vim-pandoc plugin](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc)

Comment: Yes, I use pandoc too.But if I set *.mkd as markdown.The vim-markdown plugin will not work any more. So...

Comment: @qianchenglong will not work or will not be loaded? what do you use to manage your plugins?

Comment: I use vundle for plugin from git, pathogen for non git(local etc).

Answer (score 0):

To do this without changing the plugin itself and without file system-level tricks like links, you can create redirection scripts for the `ftplugin/`, `indent/` etc. For example, `~/.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim` with the following contents:

```
runtime! ftplugin/mkd.vim
```

But of course, the best solution would be the mentioned change in the plugin itself.